# Magento API: Set dropdown attribute option for a storeview

Tags: api, magento

I am working with magento API and need to create dropdown options for different storeviews.

I found a function to to create a dropdown option for default storeview:

```
public function addAttributeOption($arg_attribute, $arg_value) 
{   
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute'); 
    $attribute_options_model= Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');   
    $attribute_code = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute); 
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);   
    $attribute_table = $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute); 
    $options = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);   
    $value['option'] = array($arg_value,$arg_value); 
    $result = array('value' => $value); 
    $attribute->setData('option',$result); 
    $attribute->save();   
}
```

This functions works fine, I can add a new attribut value for default storeview.

Example:

I have the attribute "mycolor" and call the function like

```
addAttributeOption("mycolor", "black")
```

Now I have a storeview for a german shop and like to set the german color. I would need something like

addAttributeOption("mycolor", "black", "schwarz", $storeview)

Means set the color option of storeview to schwarz where the color of the default value is black.

Does anybody has an Idea how can I do that?

Best regards

Comment: Okay, when there is no way i will solve via mysql query.

Answer (score 3):

I figure you alreay found your solution but perhaps I can help someone else who's new to Magento like I am. Today I had to find a way to import attributes (Product Attributes only that is) from an external Products-Managing-System into Magento running with multiple store views, too. I don't know where the questioner's addAttributeOption function came from but the Magento installer script offers its very own addAttributeOption(). So I took a look into Setup.php where Magento's addAttributeOption() is defined:

> {Your Magento Path}/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php

Now, in the Magento Version i'm working with (1.9.1.0) addAttributeOption() expects one argument, an array called $option. It's architecture looks as follows:

```
Array (
    'attribute_id'  => '{attributeId}',
    'value'         => array(
        '{optionId}'    => array(

            '{storeId}'    => '{labelName}',

        ),
    ),
    'delete'        =>  array(
        //...
    ),
    'order'         => array(
        //...
    )
);
```

As you can see, 'value' expects an array and this array's key determines the storeID. In most addAttributeOption()-introductions I found on the web, the storeID is hard coded to 0 with no further explanation - 0 makes it the required default admin value. So, quite obviously by now, for adding Options with StoreView-dependent labels we simply have to add an extra array value for each StoreView like this:

```
Array (
    'attribute_id'  => $attribute_id,
    'value'         => array(
        'option1'   => array(

            '0'    => 'black',              // required admin value
            '1'    => 'Schwarz (RAL 9005)', // if storeId = 1 is German
            '2'    => 'Black (RAL 9005)',   // if storeId = 2 is English

        ),
        'option2'   => array(

            '0'    => 'blue',
            '1'    => 'Blau (RAL 5015)',
            '2'    => 'Blue (RAL 5015)',

        ),
        // And so on...
    )
);
```

*Note: If your option's array-index is a number addAttributeOption() expects it to be the ID-Number of an already existing Option. This is great in case you want to update already existing options but this also means a new Option musn't be numeric. Hence I named them 'option1' & 'option2'.*

You can call addAttributeOption() like this:

```
Mage::app();
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

// ...
// generate your Options-Array
// I called it $newOptions

$installer->addAttributeOption($newOptions);

$installer->endSetup();
```